# Using Janusgraph (Java in-memory implementation), how can I commit property keys before creating an index?

Tags: java, janusgraph

I'm prototyping a java project using Janusgraph and have run into a problem. If I create a property key and commit that property key before an index is created, the index appears to be stuck in the INSTALLED state. Example code here:

```
    @Test
    public void minimalTest() throws InterruptedException {
        // build in-memory backend for janusgraph
        JanusGraph graph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "inmemory").open();
        graph.tx().rollback();
        JanusGraphManagement mgmt = graph.openManagement();
        // create test prop & commit
        String testProp = "testprop";
        mgmt.getOrCreatePropertyKey(testProp);
        mgmt.commit();
        // create test index & commit
        mgmt = graph.openManagement();
        String testIndex = "testIndex";
        mgmt.buildIndex(testIndex, Vertex.class).addKey(mgmt.getPropertyKey(testProp)).buildCompositeIndex();
        mgmt.commit();
        // attempt to wait for enabled
        ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, testIndex).status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED).call();
        System.out.println("Gets stuck in the await line above and never makes it here");
    }
```

If I comment out committing the property key & re-opening the graph management, then this code works fine. Example right here:

```
    @Test
    public void minimalTest() throws InterruptedException {
        // build in-memory backend for janusgraph
        JanusGraph graph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "inmemory").open();
        graph.tx().rollback();
        JanusGraphManagement mgmt = graph.openManagement();
        // create test prop & commit
        String testProp = "testprop";
        mgmt.getOrCreatePropertyKey(testProp);
        //mgmt.commit();
        // create test index & commit
        //mgmt = graph.openManagement();
        String testIndex = "testIndex";
        mgmt.buildIndex(testIndex, Vertex.class).addKey(mgmt.getPropertyKey(testProp)).buildCompositeIndex();
        mgmt.commit();
        // attempt to wait for enabled
        ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, testIndex).status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED).call();
        System.out.println("Gets here fine");
    }
```

What do I need to do which would allow me to create the property key in a different transaction from the index like in the first example above?

My janusgraph-core and janusgraph-inmemory versions are 1.0.0 if that matters at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to:

1. change when the rollback was occurring to run after the commit for the propertyKey took place
2. execute a schema action to enable the index after it was added.

The final code which works looks like this:

```
@Test
public void minimalTest4() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    // build in-memory backend for janusgraph
    JanusGraph graph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "inmemory").open();
    JanusGraphManagement mgmt = graph.openManagement();
    // create test prop & commit
    String testProp = "testprop";
    mgmt.getOrCreatePropertyKey(testProp);
    mgmt.commit();
    graph.tx().rollback();
    // create test index & commit
    mgmt = graph.openManagement();
    String testIndex = "testIndex";
    mgmt.buildIndex(testIndex, Vertex.class).addKey(mgmt.getPropertyKey(testProp)).buildCompositeIndex();
    mgmt.commit();
    ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, testIndex).status(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED).call();
    // enable index
    mgmt = graph.openManagement();
    mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex(testIndex), SchemaAction.ENABLE_INDEX).get();
    mgmt.commit();
    // attempt to wait for enabled
    ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, testIndex).status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED).call();
    System.out.println("Gets here fine");
}
```